# Appropriate data format during training of a SVM classifier

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, matrix, vector, svm

I'm a trying to design an svm classifier. Doing this, I stuck at a point where I am getting an error during applying fitcsm(). I understand that the error arises due to the mismatch of the appropriate data format. Would you please help me to sort out the issue?

**Input:**

I have 2000 train data of format 1 x 20 x 300 dimension which is X whereas the category data for the train is of 2000 x 1 dimension which is Y.

**Data Format:**

The data format of X{2000 X 1} is following

[image]

Each cell contains data of dimension 1 x 20 x 300 such as the following:

[image]
After applying *fitcsvm(X, Y)* the following error has arisen:

```
Invalid data type. X must be a double or single matrix.
```

Would you please suggest me the appropriate way to make fitcsvm() working?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

convert x to a matrix 2000*20*300 first, then
Flatten x to 1*6000

```
x=reshape(x,[2000,6000])
```

fitcsvm accept only matrix, the argument must be a matrix not data format like that

Comment: Yu hi. thanks for your response. Should I convert it to the matrix using squeeze?

Comment: I dont know how squeeze work. The most straightforward is looping over x and bind each elements in x together.